# jQuery append is invisible?

Tags: jquery, append

I am using append to add some text to a div container when a link is clicked. The new text which is appended is also itself a link. When the new text link is clicked the Jquery event which I have attached to this event does not happen.

If I paste the appended code straight into my HTML then the event is caught, it's almost as if the appended html cannot be seen. Have I mis-understood how the jquery append function works?

Thanks,

Alan.

EDIT **

code:

$(function(){

```
$('.tab-link').click(function(){

     alert('hello');

});

$('.tab-copy').click(function(){

     var next=$(this).data("next");

     $('#tabs-row-left').append('<div class=\"tab-folder\" id=\"IDtab'+next+'\"><a href=\"#\" class=\"tab-link\" id=\"tab'+next+'\" data-strategyid='+(next+1)+'>TEST</a></div>');


});
```

});

Here is the JS Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/M6Wcj/

If you click the plus sign you will see the new text appear, this then should be clickable like the exisiting text and should alert 'hello' but it doesn't. Weird!

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: Please post relevant parts of the code.

Comment: You are most likely attaching the jquery event like so: $(linkselector).click(function() {...}); When you should be using delegated event handlers, like so: $(document).on("click",linkselector,function() {...});

Comment: @cernunnos -- with no code shown, I'm about 99% sure that's the answer :)

Comment: @cernunnos - Please could you explain why it is better to use delegated event handlers. I've seen them but not really done much with them. Is it down to the code `$(linkselector).click(function() {...}); ` only applying to elements containing that selector on document.ready?

Comment: @BenMillane JQuery attaches event handlers to the actual elements, the new element does not exist when you are attaching the event handlers. Delegated event handlers are attached to parent elements (in the case of my example the "document" element) and are delegated to any children that match the selector, wether the children is new or not.

Comment: @cernunnos your suggestion works, if I chenge to '$(document).on("click",'a.tab-link',function(){' it works! How or why I don't fully understand

Comment: @AlanA You can read more on event handlers here: http://api.jquery.com/on/ The chapter on "Direct and delegated events" is especially interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your recently appended link has correct path to it, for example you've used `$(".class a")` , but new element will be `$(".class a a")`

Answer (score 0):

It's sounds like you need to change your your event binding to 'on', something like this:

```
$('#container').on('click', 'a', function(){
    //doSomething.
})
```